# UDK: INI files seem to be encrypted

Tags: encryption, ini, unreal-development-kit

I wanted to change the values of an INI file but these seem to be encrypted. Cant read a bit. The INI files of other UDK games are not encrypted and fully readable.

Do you know why or how they were encrypted and how to decrypt them?
Is this encryption part of the UDK also for securing the INI files by changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bulletstorm uses encrypted .inis due to you being able to cheat the skillshots

[an editor/decrypter has been made](http://www.bulletstormforum.com/bulletstorm-pc/552-bulletstorm-ini-editor.html)

not sure if any other game does it

you need to make your question more clear, this isnt about UDK, it's about a specific released unreal engine game, right?

Answer (score 0):

UDK .ini files have never been encrypted by default as far as I know. What version of UDK are you using?

Comment: Well it seems the american publisher encryptred them. There are just many unreadable signs in the INI files. And I mean in EVERY INI file